# Can't assign to literal in python 3.6.4

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to python 3.6.4, I am trying to make a game, but it says `can't assign to literal`.

here is my code:

```
`health = 5.0
print('You keep on exploring, and you find a patch of ice yams in the     snow.')
    yams = input('Will you eat them?: ')
    if yams in ['YES','Yes','yes']:
        print()
        2.50 += health
        print('Those yams were very nutritious and you felt more active.')
        print(health)
    elif yams in ['NO','No','no']:
        2.50 -= health
        print('You missed a chance to be healthier.')
        print(health)`
```

how do I rid of this error?

Comment: Change `2.50 += health` to `health += 2.50`, and in the other cases

Comment: `        2.50 += health`  You're assigning the value of health + 2.5 to the literal 2.5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As others have said, you reversed the order of the assignment.

`2.50 += health` should be `health += 2.50`

and `2.50 -= health` should be `health -= 2.50`

Also you can optimize your code a bit.

```
if yams in ['YES','Yes','yes']:
```

can be written as

```
if yams.lower().startswith('yes'):
```

The `lower()` converts your input string to lower case so case sensitivity is no longer a concern.  `startswith` check the beginning of the string for the keyword.

In this case, even if someone said "YEs I will eat some yam", your code can still accept it as a valid input.

Likewise you can do a similar thing for the No response.

Per @michael_heath's feedback, `startswith()` can introduce unexpected results if users want to be smart about it.  A cleaner way and concise way to handle the responses is to use:

`if yams.lower() in ('yes','y'):`

This way only the responses "Yes" and "Y" are accepted while case sensitivity is accounted for.  You might also want to have a handler for invalid responses.

Comment: What is acceptable? `"yesterday I said no, today I say no"`, `"yes, but yams make me sick, so no"`. Your `startswith` seems incapable to handle meaning of sentences. Taking this for granted could lead to unintended consequences.

Comment: I agree, but the way they originally designed it is flawed already.  It just seems like a good chance to introduce them to different methods of parsing responses, but how thorough they want it is their decision.  

Having said that, an easy way to handle that would be just use `.lower() in('yes','y')`

Comment: I like you last idea of `.lower() in('yes','y')`. This is a good idea to insert into your answer. Following with an alternative is quite ok if you think it may help. I may even give you a up-vote if you improve your answer with your latest idea.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I updated my answer based on this discussion.  Could always use some upvotes as I've finally came out of my lurking stage.

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is in the line:

`2.50 += health`

This says that you are trying to assign `2.50 + health`, to a literal.  You cannot assign a value to a literal.

What you are trying to do is increment `health` by `2.50`, which can be done by reversing the order of your arguments.

Change the line `2.50 += health`, to `health += 2.50` and your code will work.